# Why does this Javascript code return an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I got this exercise from freeCodeCamp.  When I try to solve it in the following way, it returns an empty array.  Why?

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {

    return arr2.splice(n, 0, arr1);
}
    frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.splice()` method returns an array containing deleted elements. Your code is requesting that 0 elements be deleted, so the returned array will of course be empty.

Comment: Hmmmmm.......let me check this out.....Thank you for answering.....

Comment: Note that `.splice()` and `.slice()` are very very different methods